# Is it possible to have same interface in javaee app and use it in CLI and GUI both?

Tags: java, api, user-interface, command-line-interface

We have a javaee application whithout any gui. To adding some records to database config. tables( entities) we use manual  sql script which is not safe and easy.
We have decided to develop gui and also CLI for our application to handle this issue.
Is it possible to have interfaces in javaee app and use then in both Gui and CLI?
From end-user point of veiw, services and parameters arr same in both gui and cli.
Something like jboss admin web console and jboss cli to deploy an artifact.

Comment: Anything's possible. Just depends on how you design it. For example, what I would do in your situation is put my database interaction logic in a service, and then let that same service code be invoked either from my web layer (via REST or other API) and my CLI.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there any standard way to design APIs in that  service ( which is responsible for db interactions, as you suggested) that will be used in/called from both web layer and CLI ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for this depending on what you want.

The most effective option create a series of quick commands run as command line options that can be run without loading the GUI and load the GUI if no command is given.  This works particularly good on short applications or on interface clients to server applications where the interface client program would launch, send the command to the server, then close.

This can be done on many platforms, not just Java.  Notable Open Source examples I can think of off the top of my head are the WineTricks Shell Script based program and the Mono based Kerbal Space Program mod management application, CKAN.

This is a tried and true way of running a utility or server remote command client, and generally works well.

For more advanced options you can use command line options to enable a command stream mode that keeps a console open to listen for commands, or a selection of a specific GUI panel.

Other functions is to allow the use of XML descriptor files to load in command behaviors from CLI or to describe how to build various control panels for the User.

Furthermore, you use the same manner can select from multiple UIs, allowing web interfaces, as well as local UIs.

Really there are a lot of options to make a single tool have a whole host of front-ends.

As of structural implementation, you may want to use a backend/frontend setup where the CLI command is the backend, but can load registered GUI frontend plugins on receiving the command to do so.   This reduces dependencies, which is always good.  Since the command line is always open to a degree, and it is very small, it should be built in by default.